# Dynamic CSS Menu that overlaps html body when menu opens

Tags: css, xhtml, css-float

I now have a dynamic CSS only menus (my first), but when the menu expands it pushes the body content below it down while the menu is open and back up when the menu closes.  What is the best CSS way to prevent this so that the menu opens overtop of the body text?  Here is the page that shows what I am talking about:

http://fundunity.com/test.htm

Updated: I should probably add that I want the menu to cover (not show) the body information when opened.

Any help is appreciated!
Brock

Comment: Learn about `position: absolute;` and `position: relative`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to absolutely position your subnav.

Give the parent element `position:relative;` then give your subnav `position:absolute`

You may then need to change some CSS / Javascript depending on how you are showing / hiding the sub nav to make it function correctly but this is the basics of how to do it.